# Consuming JSON-RPC web services in .NET

Tags: wcf, web-services, json, soap, json-rpc

A business partner has suggested building a web services library with JSON-RPC rather that SOAP. (note they are not building in .NET necessarily, but I am)

I am a potential consumer of this data.

I've used JSON for client-based Ajax calls in the past, but this web services library will be used primarily for server-side calls and syncing large amounts of data.

I don't have much experience with JSON-RPC.

Questions:

- Can I easily build a JSON-RPC
  consumer in .NET?
- Are JSON-RPC web services self
  documenting and discoverable, like a
  SOAP WSDL?
- Can I easily add a Web Reference in
  Visual Studio to a JSON-RPC web service?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I easily build a JSON-RPC consumer
>   in .NET?

Yes. JSON-RPC services are simple to consume as long as you have a robust JSON parser or formatter. [Jayrock](http://code.google.com/p/jayrock/) provides a simple client implementation [`JsonRpcClicnet`](http://code.google.com/p/jayrock/source/browse/trunk/src/Jayrock.Sandbox/JsonRpcClient.cs?r=795) that you can use to build a consumer. There is also a small [demo sample](http://code.google.com/p/jayrock/source/browse/branches/jelly-integration/samples/JsonRpcClientDemo/Program.cs?r=783) included.

> Are JSON-RPC web services self
>   documenting and discoverable, like a
>   SOAP WSDL?

No, there is nothing standardized but there are ideas being floated around like [Service Mapping Description Proposal](http://groups.google.com/group/json-schema/web/service-mapping-description-proposal).

> Can I easily add a Web Reference in
>   Visual Studio to a JSON-RPC web
>   service?

This can work if the server-side implementation provides a WSDL-based description of the JSON-RPC service but none are known to provide this to date.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Jayrock](http://jayrock.berlios.de/).

> Jayrock is a modest and an open source
>   (LGPL) implementation of  JSON and
>   JSON-RPC for the Microsoft .NET
>   Framework, including ASP.NET. What can
>   you do with Jayrock? In a few words,
>   Jayrock allows clients, typically 
>   JavaScript in web pages, to be able to
>   call into server-side methods using
>   JSON as the wire format and JSON-RPC
>   as the procedure invocation protocol.
>   The methods can be called
>   synchronously or asynchronously.

Comment: Isn't Jayrock for building services as opposed to consuming them?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I easily build a JSON-RPC consumer in .NET?

Shouldn't be difficult as long as you know what you're doing.

> Are JSON-RPC web services self documenting and discoverable, like a SOAP WSDL?

Discoverable yes, documenting in as much as you can get function names and parameter lists. (not entirely sure what you're asking for as far as documentation goes).

> Can I easily add a Web Reference in Visual Studio to a JSON-RPC web service?

I don't think so, no. (Though, I have no idea, it's possible. My experience with JSON-RPC is in PHP/JS mostly)

Relevant links:

- http://json-rpc.org/wiki/specification
- http://json.org/
- http://techblog.procurios.nl/k/618/news/view/14605/14863/How-do-I-write-my-own-parser-for-JSON.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could have a look at json-wsp which is much like json-rpc but with a discription specification. It is implemented as an interface in Ladon for python.
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ladon

Answer (score 0):

I have some sample Json-Rpc 2.0 clients for .net and windows phone 7 in the [Json-RPC.NET](http://jsonrpc2.codeplex.com) sources.

Check them out: [.Net Client](https://jsonrpc2.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/18174#63257) and [WP7 Client](https://jsonrpc2.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/18174#282775)

Comment: I think you should say that you're the author of jsonrpc2.